# How to change the body's background color with buttons using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to change the entire background color of the body to the color that the button is assigned to. I'm new to javascript but I looked over the internet and my notes and couldn't find a problem. I think I'm just missing something very simple orrrrr i could be wayyy off.

THE HTML

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button onclick="white()">
                    <p>White</p>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="red()">
                    <p>Red</p>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="yellow()">
                    <p>Yellow</p>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button onclick="blue()">
                    <p>Blue</p>
                </button>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
function white() {
    document.body.backgroundColor("white");
}

function red() {
    document.body.backgroundColor("red");
}

function yellow() {
    document.body.backgroundColor("yellow");
}

function blue() {
    document.body.backgroundColor("blue");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backgroundColor` is an attribute, not a function. And its a `style` attribute. Change your lines to this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
```

Furthermore, the `onClick` attribute is kind of outdated. You can try to work with event handlers in JavaScript itself instead ([more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)).

Comment: Worked like a charm :D. Also if the onClick function is oudated what do you suggest I use. Since I'm new I'd like to use the more modern techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, you just need to make sure you select the `body` element of the window correctly:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor
```

So your functions would look like:

```
function white() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
....
```

**Note:**

Make sure that you put your JavaScript at the *end* of the webpage too, it you aren't already!

Comment: So would my functions be like the second example bc there exact to taht or are you trying to show me to do the first one.

Comment: @cosmichero2025 my mistake - I forgot to edit. See my new response

Comment: ohhhhh now i get it. I already used the one the answer from someone from above but i like this way of doing it as well :D

Comment: @cosmichero2025 Which ever works best for you! Glad I could help =)

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white"; // or any other color`

More info on the `style` property in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).